# exclude search paths with git-files. Show only files in my repo without untracked files

Tags: git, unix

I have for example, xml directory - committed.
I want to show all files in my repo and use `git ls-files`
But I want to exclude 'xml' dir and exclude untracked files.

My command is:

```
 git ls-files --exclude=xml/
```

But it doesn't work.  I understood that it's only on untracked files.

I want:
exclude directory and files. Show only files in my repo without untracked files.
How to do it ? I can do it with grep and pipe but pipe added overhead.

The question is, is it possible to offer an effective solution to optimize running time?

Thanks,
Alex